# User not getting prompted to allow app access to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

To get a token,  I am calling:
  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,account, "oauth2:"      +"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata");

Which will always give me a token, so my code works,  BUT I am expecting(at least the first time) to get a UserRecoverableAuthException so I can use that intent on the exception to prompt the user for action.   The action in this case is granting my app access to that user's Google drive storage.

From the web site,  I disconnect the app from the drive,  run my app, files get written to my gdrive,  and I see, from the website,  that the app is connected to my drive.

Why is the user not getting prompted to allow access?

Answer (score 0):

If user has already given permissions for you app for that scope, no UserRecoverableAuthException will be thrown.

Comment: Sure,  but won't going to the web and selecting "Disconnect from Drive" for your app take those permissions away?

Comment: Yes. The question is how to ask for permission again.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in my case the Authorization dialog wasn't been showed because I added singleInstance to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

Removing from the AndroidManifest

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

fixed this problem and a couple of other strange transition effects between activities.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you connect your app to drive it asks for permission by itself when you send the account name.

The Exception you are expecting is only thrown if the user Disconnects the app.

Try disconnecting the app and then read/write to drive. It should throw this Exception.